# Why Did Voldemort Kill Snape?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, severus-snape

I know that the answer to that question is to obtain the Elder Wand, but I think that approach doesn't really make sense.

We know that death is not necessary for the Elder Wand to change hands (Grindelwald stole it from Gregorovitch, and Albus obtained by beating Grindelwald in a non fatal duel) which means we know Voldemort didn't have to kill Snape to obtain the wand, that was just one way of doing it.

Snape was a powerful wizard(maybe one of the strongest of the death eaters) and had proven himself more useful than almost any Death Eater(providing years of information on Dumbledore and later killing him), Voldemort probably didn't want to kill him unless it was absolutely necessary.

Couldn't there have been some other way to get the wand from Severus? Like challenging Snape to a non-fatal duel for ownership of the wand, or perhaps even giving Severus the wand and then stealing it, Grindelwald style?

Comment: Which means *we* know that killing is not the only way.

Comment: It's his signature spell. Of course there could have been another way but he didn't truly understand wand lore nor enough about the Elder Wand. The fact he had Nagini kill Severus is obviously for his protection but since at that point Harry was the rightful owner it wouldn't have mattered anyway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Because Voldemort is sure that **killing** is the only way.

   All the theories of winning its allegience that you listed in the question ("*We know that death is not necessary*") never even occurred to Voldemort, whose solution to pretty much any problem is "Avada Kedavra"

   > The Elder Wand cannot serve me properly, Severus, because I am not its true master. The Elder Wand belongs **to the wizard who killed its last owner**. You killed Albus Dumbledore. While you live, Severus, the Elder Wand cannot truly be mine.”
2. Because Snape became less useful at that point, so the downsides of killing him aren't there to balance the decision.

   > —and it is doing so without your help,” said Voldemort in his high, clear voice. “Skilled wizard though you are, Severus, I do not think you will make much difference now. We are almost there... almost.
3. Please note that it was literally, the only solution that occured to him, and he honestly didn't just do it because he was tired of Snape.

   While he may have been play-acting for Snape in their dialogue later in the scene, he obviously was NOT play-acting when talking to Nagini earlier:

   > “Snape. Now. I need him. There is a—service—I require from him. Go.”
   >   Frightened, stumbling a little through the gloom, Lucius left the room. Voldemort continued to stand there, twirling the wand between his fingers, staring at it.
   >   **“It is the only way, Nagini**,” he whispered, and he looked around, and there was the great thick snake, now suspended in midair, twisting gracefully within the enchanted, protected space he had made for her, a starry, transparent sphere somewhere between a glittering cage and a tank.

All quotes are *Deathly Hallows, Chapter 32, "The Elder Wand"*

Comment: Plus, we don't know at any point where the wand's allegiance truly lies. It is well possible Dumbledore never was the wand's master for example - as later the want fails to work for Voldemort.

Comment: @WeckarE. Oh yes we do know that he was the owner. If he wasn't when Draco disarmed him Draco wouldn't have become the rightful owner. And if that happened then Harry wouldn't have then been the rightful owner once he disarmed Draco in the Manor. Furthermore Rowling wrote about this - that if Voldemort knew Draco was the owner he would have been killed immediately. And finally the reason the wand failed Voldemort is exactly because Harry was the owner and not Voldemort. So your comment is completely wrong.

Comment: @Pryftan The ONLY evidence we ever have for this chain of events is Harry using it to fix his own wand. None of the other 'owners' ever used it for otherwise impossible magic.

Comment: @WeckarE. False. Rowling even says otherwise: **Draco never realises that he becomes, for the best part of a year, the true owner of the Elder Wand. It is as well that he does not, partly because the Dark Lord is skilled in Legilimency** Maybe you should look into what I said rather than believe yourself infallible? I even said that Rowling stated it and you ignored that. Well I just quoted it. Furthermore Harry directly warns Voldemort. Put another way you're 100% wrong whether you admit or not. https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/draco-malfoy

Comment: @WeckarE. I also advise you to reread the chapter King's Cross. Dumbledore and Harry discuss it directly: **I was fit to own the Elder Wand, and not to boast of it, and not to kill with it. I was permitted to tame and to use it, because I took it, not for gain, but to save others from it.** Put those two quotes together and what do you have? You have that I was right in the first place. Maybe you forgot, maybe you didn't read the books maybe something else entirely. But yes we do have evidence that Harry ended up being the master of it.

Comment: @Pryftan Okay, I would never say I am infallible, so please leave your ad hominems at the door. Basically, I work by the assumption that if evidence is not in the book, it does not exist. The author is in no way an authority on a work, literarily speaking. If it is not in the text, it does not exist in the universe of the story. The story provides that Dumbledore indeed owned the wand, but not that he was true master. I am willing to concede that such is quite likely considering the circumstances, though, as he did actively use it. Anything else is conjecture, in the world of the text.

Comment: @Pryftan Additionally, the exact mechanics of what will transfer the role of Master of the Elder Wand are unclear and, if the characters are to be believed, almost arbitrary. The wand Harry took from Draco was another wand, and it was taken by physical force rather than magic. There is no reasonable argument to be made this would lead to a transference, with everything else we know about the wand taken into account: It seeks out powerful wizards, supposedly to lead them to their doom. As a muggle could have done what Harry did in this case, It makes no sense for the act to qualify.

Comment: @WeckarE. That was no ad hominem. Not even remotely close. If you read my message again and try and think of how it might be meant another way (you do understand the irony here I hope?) you might actually realise what I was trying to say. And yes he did suggest he was the true master whether you admit it or not. Rowling also stated it. She had Harry point it out too: because of what he learnt from Dumbledore as well as introspection.

Comment: @WeckarE. As for your last point: What Harry did counts as disarming. And it's especially true for the Elder Wand because it is all about the most powerful. As for your Muggle statement: that's immaterial because a Muggle couldn't use a wand with any effect (Rowling has also stated this). I don't see how or where you get the idea that the Elder Wand leads to their doom (as in that is it's goal) seeing as how the story is just that: a story.